# How do you turn on a send verification prompt for text messages on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sms

My mother has a problem that she often accidentally hits send while typing a text message (i.e. SMS). Is there any way to turn on some sort of "Are you sure you want to send?" verification prompt for text messages? She's on iOS 13.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature as of now. I think one possible solution can be changing the keyboard layout i.e. using one-handed keyboard placed on the left side *[Settings > General > Keyboards]*. This would shift the keyboard away from the send button and thereby prevent accidentally hitting send.